# KVM reconnects internet on guest if I disconnect

Tags: kvm-virtualization, internet

When I disconnect the internet on any one of my many virtual machines (in this case Debian) via the wicd network manager, after about 10 minutes or so it's magically reconnected. This is very unpleasant behavior as I have internet bandwidth caps and can't have the internet on these guests connected all the time for a myriad of reasons.

I suspect it's KVM because many of the virtual machines I migrated from virtualbox and none of them had this behavior before now.

Is there any way to disable this periodic check? Maybe a workaround of some sort?

I have looked everywhere for some kind of information on the issue to no avail. It appears this is the right site for this issue although I apologize if it is not.

Comment: Just create an iptables rule to block the traffic.

Comment: How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The account I posted with was temporary, so unfortunately I will be unable to mark any answers as the correct one. In any event I've found a workaround that works for me.

I use gnome-scheduler and a set of custom scripts to check the time at a set interval for the most internet-intense VMs. In this way, I can minimize as much damage as possible from whatever the heck is happening here.

*PeriodicNetCheck.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
H=$(date +%H)
if (( 5 <= 10#$H && 10#$H < 23 )); then 
    bash /home/browsing/Documents/NetMngr.sh d
fi
```

*NetMngr.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
[ $# -eq 0 ] && echo "ERROR: No arguments supplied." && exit

case "$1" in
*[cC]*) option=-c;;
*[dD]*) option=-x;;
*) echo "ERROR: Invalid Argument." && exit;;
esac
wicd-cli --wired $option wired-default
```

In this case, I was already using NetMngr.sh to connect the internet at the appropriate times.

This is an extremely unsatisfactory answer however as it cannot be used for more active VMs that I may need internet off more sporadically. I am still actively searching for a better solution as well as looking into iptables *although having to use something so complex for such a simple problem is just as unsatisfactory for me!*